# alias help='compgen -c | sort -b' doesn't work in .bashrc but only in terminal

Tags: bash, linux-mint, terminal, alias

.bashrc:

```
alias cls="echo -en '\033c\033[3J'"
alias help='compgen -c | sort -b'
```

terminal:

```
cls
```

works fine.

```
help
```

gives me the error:

```
"ort: opzione non valida -- "
Try 'sort --help' for more information.
```

Terminal:

```
alias help='compgen -c | sort -b'
help
```

works fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you *run* `help` inside .bashrc, or do you get an error defining the alias, or does the alias not get defined, or ...?

Comment: If the error message is literally "ort: ..." then it appears there are some non-printing characters in the .bashrc version of the alias.

Answer (score 2):

`man bash` explains it:

> Aliases  are  not  expanded  when  the  shell  is  not  interactive,  unless   the
>          `expand_aliases` shell option is set using `shopt`

Enabling the option in a script is not common, though. Declare a function instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved with:

```
if [ -f /etc/skel/.bashrc ]; then . /etc/skel/.bashrc; fi
```

at the first line.